Problemas para migrar mi aplicación web escrita en Symfony a Google Cloud Platform, confusión entre las distintas posibilidades
Tengo dos sitios web basados en Wordpress alojados desde hace varios años en un hosting compartido, ambos con su base de datos MySQL.
Uno de los sitios webs tiene poco tráfico y acabo de migrarlo a Symfony, por ser el más simple. Actualmente este sitio más pequeño funciona en Symfony, pero se me hizo muy complicado desplegarlo, por las limitaciones en el hosting compartido (no acceso como root, etc).
Mi idea es migrar también el otro sitio a Symfony. Este sitio tiene también una API que sirve información para una aplicación con unos 10,000 usuarios y tendencia a crecer en los próximos años.
Hasta ahora ha funcionado bien, aunque en momentos pico he tenido problemas de exceso de recursos. Ya en el pasado la empresa de hosting me invitaba a pasar a un VPS, pero el precio de los mismos me parece algo elevado para mis posibilidades y no tengo mucho conocimiento en manejo de servidores, cPanel, etc.
Estuve mirando en Google Cloud, y creo que alguna de sus ofertas podría ser más económica para mi caso, específicamente, Compute Engine, donde podría contratar instancias para instalar la versión de PHP que necesite, así como MySQL y subir mi futura aplicación migrada a Symfony. App Engine lo descarto, es más fácil, pero tendría que contratar la base de datos y el costo de la misma no está a mi alcance.
Mi problema es que no encuentro una orientación clara en el universo de Google. Creo tener claro que lo mejor para mí sería Compute Engine (porque es lo que parece ajustarse a mi presupuesto), pero  no sé cómo se complementa eso. Por ejemplo, ¿debo crear Balanceadores de Carga? ¿Debo tener un CDN? ¿Debo usar Kubernetes? ¿Cómo hago para apuntar mi dominio a ese universo una vez tenga todo configurado en Google Cloud? ¿Si configuro una o más instancias de Compute Engine y estas se apagan, qué ocurre con mi base de datos?
He estado buscando en la web si había algún tutorial al respecto, pero no hay nada claro. Por ejemplo, no encuentro nada sobre desplegar una aplicación basada en Symfony usando Compute Engine. Hay un tutorial que habla de usar Cloud Run y tutoriales que hablan de App Engine, pero nada de Compute Engine y Symfony.
Mi pregunta es si es factible lo que intento hacer y cómo podría hacerlo.
La pregunta es un poco en el aire, si tengo que precisar algo más, me lo pueden señalar en comentarios, estoy algo perdido entre tantas posibilidades. Busco una orientación clara, o al menos saber si esto es factible y de qué modo.
